# URDF and RVIZ2: cylinder not showing

Tags: ros2, joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am working through the urdf_tutorials and I found that rviz doesn't show the cylinder model correctly, it only shows the circle on the floor and isn't 'extruded'. The box and sphere work fine and are shown in rviz. There aren't any errors shown in the terminal.

[Link to rviz display](https://imgur.com/a/qvfqo9J)

**I am using:**
ROS2 - galactic,
RVIZ2 version Alpha

Packages:
joint_state_publisher
joint_state_publisher_gui

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 64bit with kernel 3.36.8

It looks like this is a bug in the parser? Thanks for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389967/urdf-and-rviz2:-cylinder-not-showing/) by [laziest_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/88803/laziest_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2021-11-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-03**:
Looks like a repeat question. Take a look at https://answers.ros.org/question/374069/rviz2-only-render-boxes/

**Comment by [laziest_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/88803/laziest_robot/) on 2021-11-04**:
Thanks osilva, putting LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8" to .bashrc solved my issue.

echo 'export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"' >>~/.bashrc

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-04**:
Glad to hear it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Putting LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8" to .bashrc solved my issue:

```
echo 'export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"' >>~/.bashrc
```

I have adjusted the ROS2 documentation to include this step. [Pull Request](https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/pull/2157)

---

Originally posted by [laziest_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/88803/laziest_robot/) with karma: 41 on 2021-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2